# I need an efficient algorithm for best matching

Tags: c#, algorithm, matching

I have, for instance, 10 teams and I need to match them. 
The criteria for matching are:

1. Two teams are matched only one time.
2. Teams with closest score must be matched (Score is property of Team class, type is double).

It could be iterated 9 (n-1) times max and this is what I try to do, go further as I can. 
At the end of each iteration, points of teams increase randomly.
I populated my list with random data.

```
List<Team>  _teams = new List<Team>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    _teams.Add(new Team("Team "+i,MyExtensions.RandomNumber(31)));
}

private static readonly Random Rand = new Random();

public static int RandomNumber(int max)
{
    return Rand.Next(max);
}
```

My team class:

```
public class Team
{
    private string _name;
    private double _score;
    private List<Team> _matchedTeams;
    private Team _currentMatch;

    public Team CurrentMatch
    {
        get { return _currentMatch; }
        set { _currentMatch = value; }
    }

    public List<Team> MatchedList
    {
        get { return _matchedTeams; }
        set { _matchedTeams = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public double Score
    {
        get { return _score; }
        set { _score = value; }
    }

   public Team(string name, double score)
    {
        _matchedTeams = new List<Team>();
        _name = name;
        _score = score;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name + " - (" + _score + ")";
    }
}
```

And here's my extension method to get closest match;

```
public static Team FindClosest(this List<Team> list, Team team)
{
    var orderedItems =
        list.Where(p => p != team && !p.MatchedList.Contains(team)).OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x.Score - team.Score));
    return orderedItems.FirstOrDefault();
}

var nearestMatch = _teams.FindClosest(_teams.ElementAt(0));
```

Actually, I am trying to make a bridge game fixture calculator. For each round different teams must be matched and matched teams should be equal (or close) strength. But for next rounds, because of team match uniqueness is first criterion and we must arrange a match for people, we must bend the rules of score (point) closeness.

So it will result something like that;

Algorithm runs...

First Round;
Team1-Team2 ; Team3-Team4 ; Team5-Team6 .....

scores are updated by user at the end of the round1
Algorithm runs...

Second Round;
Team1-Team7 ; Team3-Team8 ; Team4-Team9 .....

.....

scores are updated by user at the end of the round8
Algorithm runs...

Ninth Round;
Team1-Team9; Team2-Team7; Team3-Team5 .....

scores are updated by user at the end of the round9
Algorithm runs...

No more match.

I prefer an algorithm like backtracking instead of brute force or random trial-and-error.
Can you suggest me an algorithm, a method to solve my problem?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably more appropriate for CodeReview SE. Also, could you provide a reference for "backtracking"? I've never heard of that algorithm before.

Comment: A dynamic programming method for NP-complete problems  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

Comment: The first two links I found on that are way over my simple engineering head :). I hope you get a good answer! You may also consider asking on ComputerScience SE. Practically speaking, the solution you have is probably the easiest to understand, and with such a low value of *n* any optimisations aren't going to help much.

Comment: Define "closest match". Also your understanding of backtracking seems wrong, it has little to do with DP. In fact it is what most people would refer to as brute-force, only with some pruning

Comment: Closest match refers group 2 teams having nearest points. And I mean, while saying backtracking, instead of trying all possible combinations, prune some branches to lower complexity. I think it differs backtracking with brute-force, no?

Comment: What is the *global* optimization goal? Minimum total squared point distance? Minimum maximum absolute distance? Closest match is a local criterion, you can't match every point to its closest neighbor in general.

Comment: My team class has a "Point" property, which is double value. I will compare them, Math.Abs(teamA.Point - teamB.Point)

Comment: @EmreAtaseven I realize that, but what do you want to optimize globally? The total sum of all such distances? What if there is an odd number of teams?

Comment: I agree with Niklas B. that the function to optimize should be defined better. For instance, what would be the best matching for the set {1,10, 11, 20} and why?

Comment: I will add some more definition to question.

Comment: Actually your edit does still not answer my question.

Comment: We are doing it by hand calculation now by using excel, we are sorting points and start to match from top to down.By your sample set {1,10,11,20}  20 matches with 11 , 10 matches with 1

Comment: And team count must be even always.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the teams by number of points, and then take pairs of teams starting from the beginning of the sorted list.  Clearly the second-place team is the only possible team that is closest in points to the first-place team.  If you don't pair the first-place team with the second-place team, but instead pair the second-place team with the third-place team, then the best match for the first-place team will be the fourth-place team.  Pairing teams out of order in the sorted list will only increase the points disparity.

To illustrate, assume that there are 4 teams named A,B,C,D.  The difference in points between the teams is d1,d2,d3

```
A    B    C    D
  d1   d2   d3
```

If the pairings are AB and CD, then the set of differences is { d1, d3 }.
If the pairings are BC and AD, then the set of differences is { d2, (d1+d2+d3) }.
I don't know of any metric where the second set is preferable to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly state an objective function you are trying to optimize. If it's to find a minimum of sum of absolute values of differences between points for pairs, then I agree with another answer, you simply sort the teams by points and then pair them off two teams at a time from left to right and you can prove this gives the optimal pairing. If your objective function is different, then it may be harder to optimize, maybe even NP-hard depending on what your objective function is. But the point is we can't help if you if you just say "teams closest in points must be paired together" because it's possible to have a team with two neighbors on opposite sides that are equally close in points, such that the other neighbors of the two neighbors are far away, and then you can only pair up the team with one of its close neighbors.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make a bridge game fixture calculator. For each round different teams must be matched and matched teams should be equal (or close) strength. But for next rounds, because of team match uniqueness is first criterion and we must arrange a match for people, we must bend the rules of score (point) closeness.

Answer (score 0):

You will need [this course](https://class.coursera.org/optimization-002).
The dynamic programming may be too slow. Maybe the `Local search`, or other method would be more efficient. You could read the videos about `Local Search` first.

Comment: Thank you, i subscribed to lesson

Comment: I suggest you elaborate a bit on how to use local search for this problem (or comment instead if you're not up to doing this), and, in general, move away from the "see this link" approach to answering, as we prefer [so] posts to be self-contained, i.e. it should contain sufficient details to answer the question in the answer itself.

Comment: @Dukeling, You are right. I am learning that course now. And the course has 5 programming assignments. All of them are NP-Hard problems. The original problem is like how to make team schedules, and I had seen some video on the course about a schedule problem. The course can help to get an idea how to overcome this problem, but it could not give a direct, concrete solution on this problem. English is not my native Language, so I prefer to give a short answer :)